Infinite Loop with rxjs: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded
I have started to work on this codebase, and haven't used RxJS before, though I think more the issue here is how the dependencies are working, rather than a RxJS issue.
The line that causes the looping to be triggered is in SelectorColumn and here:
  const { reduxSelector, unwrappedItems, mapper, emptyMessage } = hydrator(
    columnData.item,
    columnIndex,
  );

I am not sure if the hydrator is a concept in RxJS but I could not find anything on it. I have then tried to go backwards through components to see where the rerendering is being triggered. But without any real state that I can see, I get lost.
LocationSelector
export const LocationSelector = () => {
  const currentLocationId = 2;
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const [locationSelectorState, setSelectorStateFromObservable] = useState<
    Map<ItemId, ItemCheckedStateTree>
  >(locationSelectorState$.getValue());

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = locationSelectorState$.subscribe(
      setSelectorStateFromObservable,
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const handleSelectorDone = (state: Map<ItemId, ItemCheckedStateTree>) => {
    setLocationSelectorState(state);
    setLocationSelectorVisible(false);
  };

  const handleSelectorCancel = () => setLocationSelectorVisible(false);

  // TODO Bit of an issue with the Selector in general – it is not reactive.
  // If the state of this LocationSelector component changes, for example,
  // this hydrator is not re-invoked. This means that the Selector will not
  // re-render. A small knot in the logic which we have worked around here, but
  // a 'useSelectorHydrator' hook would be a good idea.
  const hydrator = (
    location?: SelectorItem,
    columnIndex?: number,
  ): SelectorHydrator => {
    const locationToSelectId = location?.id ?? currentLocationId;
    if (columnIndex === 0 && locationToSelectId) {
      dispatch(
        locationEndpoints.getLocationDetails.initiate({
          locationId: locationToSelectId,
        }),
      );
      return {
        reduxSelector: locationEndpoints.getLocationDetails.select({
          locationId: locationToSelectId,
        }),
        mapper: locationDetailMapper,
      };
    }

    const query = {
      immediateChildrenOnly: true,
      locationId: locationToSelectId ? +locationToSelectId : undefined,
    };
    dispatch(locationEndpoints.getLocations.initiate(query));
    return {
      reduxSelector: locationEndpoints.getLocations.select(query),
      mapper: locationMapper,
    };
  };

  return (
    <Selector
      hydrator={hydrator}
      state={locationSelectorState}
      title=" Location Selector"
      icon={faCrosshairs}
      onCancel={handleSelectorCancel}
      onDone={handleSelectorDone}
    />
  );
};

MetricsBuildQuery
interface Props {
  isShowingResults: boolean;
  setShowingResults: Function;
}

const dateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS";

export const MetricsBuildQuery = ({
  isShowingResults,
  setShowingResults,
}: Props) => {
  const currentLocationId = 2;

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const { data: locationDetail, error } = useGetLocationDetailsQuery({
    locationId: currentLocationId,
  });

  const [selectedLocations, setSelectedLocations] = useState<SelectorItem[]>(
    [],
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = selectedLocations$.subscribe(setSelectedLocations);
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  // Set the query metric for API call =========================================
  const [selectedPointIds, setSelectedPointIdsFromObservable] = useState<
    number[]
  >([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = selectedPointIds$.subscribe(
      setSelectedPointIdsFromObservable,
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  // Pre-fetch the assets for the selected locations ===========================
  useEffect(() => {
    selectedLocations.forEach((option) =>
      dispatch(
        assetsEndpoints.getAssets.initiate({
          locationId: option?.id as number,
        }),
      ),
    );
    setPointSelectorState(new Map());
  }, [selectedLocations, dispatch]);

  // Set first location as selected ============================================
  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentLocationId && locationDetail) {
      const currentLocationSelectorItem = locationDetailMapper(locationDetail);
      setLocationSelectorState(
        createCheckedItem(currentLocationSelectorItem[0]),
      );
    }
  }, [currentLocationId, locationDetail]);

  // Time range ================================================================
  const [timeRange, setTimeRange] = useState<TimeRange | undefined>();
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = timeRange$.subscribe(setTimeRange);
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  // Location Selector visibility ==============================================
  const [locationSelectorVisible, setLocationSelectorVisible] =
    useState<boolean>(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = locationSelectorVisible$.subscribe(
      setLocationSelectorVisible,
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  // Point Selector visibility =================================================
  const [pointSelectorVisible, setPointSelectorVisible] =
    useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = pointSelectorVisible$.subscribe(
      setPointSelectorVisible,
    );
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const [hasPoints, setHasPoints] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = hasPoints$.subscribe(setHasPoints);
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const handleRunQuery = () => {
    setPointQueryPointIds(selectedPointIds.join(","));
    if (timeRange) {
      setPointQueryTimeRange(
        format(timeRange.customStartTime, dateFormatString),
        format(timeRange.customEndTime, dateFormatString),
      );
    }
    setShowingResults(true);
  };

  const ChooseLocationsMemo = React.memo(ChooseLocations);
  const PointSelectorMemo = React.memo(PointSelector);
  const LocationSelectorMemo = React.memo(LocationSelector);

  return (
    <>
      {/* TODO Need to memoise these components */}
      {locationSelectorVisible && <LocationSelectorMemo />}
      {pointSelectorVisible && <PointSelectorMemo />}
      <Paper
        noPadding={true}
        header={
          <PaperHeader
            title="Build Query"
            icon={CalendarTodayOutlinedIcon}
            toolbar={
              <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="flex-end" spacing={1}>
                <Button onClick={() => handleRunQuery()} disabled={!hasPoints}>
                  {isShowingResults ? "Re-run Query" : "Run Query"}
                </Button>
              </Stack>
            }
          />
        }
      >
        <div tw="flex m-4 gap-6">
          <div tw="flex flex-col gap-4 flex-1">
            {/* TODO Need to memoise these components */}
            <ChooseRangeOption />
            <ChooseLocationsMemo />
            <ChoosePoints />
          </div>
          <ChooseRange />
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </>
  );
};

SelectorColumn
const dummySelector = createSelector(() => null);

const defaultStyle = {
  width: 224,
  height: 400,
};

export const SelectorColumn = ({
  hydrator,
  onItemsFetched,
  checkedState,
  onDilateItem,
  onCheckedChange,
  columnIndex,
  columnData,
  highlightedItemId,
  leavesOnly,
}: Props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<SelectorItem[]>([]);
  const [itemsAvailable, setItemsAvailable] = useState(false);
  const [filterInput, setFilterInput] = useState("");

  const filteredList = useMemo(
    () => {
      return items.filter((item) =>
        item.description
          .toLocaleLowerCase()
          .includes(filterInput.toLocaleLowerCase()),
      )},
    [items, filterInput],
  );

  let isLoading = !itemsAvailable;
  let data;

  const [springs, api] = useSpring(() => {
    return {
    from: { left: columnIndex === 0 ? 0 : -defaultStyle.width },
    config: {
      duration: 200,
    },
  }});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && items.length) {
      api.start({ to: { left: 0 } });
    }
  }, [isLoading, items]);

  const { reduxSelector, unwrappedItems, mapper, emptyMessage } = hydrator(
    columnData.item,
    columnIndex,
  );
  const selectorResult = useAppSelector(reduxSelector ?? dummySelector) as {
    isLoading: boolean;
    data: any;
  };

  if (selectorResult && isLoading) {
    isLoading = selectorResult.isLoading;
    data = selectorResult.data;
  }

  if (unwrappedItems) {
    if (unwrappedItems.length && !itemsAvailable) {
      setItems(unwrappedItems);
      setItemsAvailable(true);
      onItemsFetched(unwrappedItems);
    }
  } else if (data && !itemsAvailable) {
    const fetchedItems = mapper ? mapper(data) : data || [];  // Fallback to empty array if data is undefined
    setItems(fetchedItems);
    setItemsAvailable(true);
    onItemsFetched(fetchedItems);
  }


  const transRef = useSpringRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading) {
      transRef.start();
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  const renderSelectorItem = (props: ListChildComponentProps) => {

    const { index, style } = props;
    const selectorItem = filteredList[index];

    // Safer to use item ID rather than index here?
    // I mean, the index is as unique as the ID, so perhaps it doesn't matter
    const handleCheckboxChange = () => {
      onCheckedChange(columnIndex, selectorItem);
    };

    return (
      <div
        key={selectorItem.id}
        css={[
          tw`flex h-10 justify-between items-center px-4 border-b border-component-dark-1 w-full gap-1`,
          highlightedItemId === selectorItem.id && tw`bg-ctrl-bg`,
        ]}
        style={style}
      >
        <div tw="flex gap-8 w-full overflow-hidden">
          <Checkbox
            label={selectorItem.description}
            checked={!!checkedState?.get(selectorItem.id)}
            indeterminate={checkedState?.get(selectorItem.id) === CheckedState.Indeterminate}
            onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
            disabled={leavesOnly && !!selectorItem.childIds}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          {selectorItem.childIds?.length && (
            <FontAwesomeIcon
              icon={faAngleRight}
              tw="text-black text-sm cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => onDilateItem(selectorItem)}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  const handleFilterChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFilterInput(event.target.value || "");  // Fallback to empty string if undefined or null
  };

  const handleFilterClearClicked = () => {
    setFilterInput("");
  };

  return (
    <div tw="relative overflow-hidden h-[400px] w-[224px] border-r border-component-dark-3">
      {isLoading ? (
        <div tw="flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full">
          <Spinner />
        </div>
      ) : items.length ? (
        <div tw="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
          <div tw="grow">
            <animated.div
              tw="absolute top-0 left-0"
              css={[tw`absolute h-full shadow-selector`]}
              id="test"
              style={springs}
            >
              <FixedSizeList
                height={355}
                width={defaultStyle.width}
                itemSize={46}
                itemCount={filteredList.length}
                overscanCount={3}
              >
                {/*
  // @ts-ignore */}
                {renderSelectorItem}
              </FixedSizeList>
            </animated.div>
          </div>
          <SelectorFilterInput
            value={filterInput}
            onChange={handleFilterChange}
            onClearClicked={handleFilterClearClicked}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div tw="flex items-center justify-center h-full w-full">
          <Text variant="noResult" tw="w-7/12 text-center">
            {emptyMessage}
          </Text>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};


While not a particularlly popular question :D
The issue was using the HOC connect on the root of the app.
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  state,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);

The app was writing in React 14 and then, for the latest component react 18 and functional with. It was causing too many rewrites down the chain. While in the root of the App.js it has connect, but then is not using any state. So removal of this fixed the re-rending issue.
